# The # (hash) does not work in angular 2 templates

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular 2.
As I read through Angular 2 tutorials on the web, the # (hash) is used to declare local variables in the template. But every time I use #, the parser throws some parsing exceptions.

For example if I use `<div *ngFor="#item of items">` following exception happnes, but if I use `let` instead of `#` everything goes fine.

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: Template Parse Error:
Parse Error: Unexpected token # at column ....
```

Do I miss some configuration for Angular 2 parser?

P.S. By the way I'm using Angular 2 2.5.x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an old syntax. That was the syntax in angular 2 beta releases. Now, it is different.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
```